# Correct Placement of Nouns in "Referring" And "Introduction" Sentences

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I've a client A, for whom I did some work. After some time, a person contacted me and said that client A told me to hire you for this project. The person became my client B.

Later, when I want to thanks client A then do the following sentences will be correct?

> "Thank you very much for referring client B to me."
>
> "Thank you very much for introducing me to client B."

Comment: I'd stick with *introducing*. In most contexts, *referrals* are much more likely to imply an established business arrangement (which might *further* imply that you as the beneficiary should be ***paying*** client A a "finder's fee" for bringing you in more business).

Comment: Did you ever consider ***recommendation***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact **you are raising a management- related question.**
It all depends what you want to say. Both the sentences are OK.
In your place I shall say:

*Thank you very much for introducing me  to client B. I could not have asked for a better introduction.*